# Is there a way to show areas not covered by any layers in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, layers

Does The GIMP have some sort of function to highlight areas of the background where that are not overlapped by any layers?

I'm making a sprite for CSS, and I have a lot of pics with different sizes. I'm trying to use any free space that I can get, but because over 90% of these images have transparent background, so I can not see the borders of layers. I can't see where and how much background space is free for other small pics.

Like this:
[image: no layer overlay]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Gimp no layer pattern]

You have to hide the default white background layer to see it.

Comment: Hmmm, you have wrong understand me, it must be look like this: http://i.imgur.com/HobDjw2.jpg

Comment: @BASILIO: ah, ok. I don't know of an easy way to do that. I added that image to the question for you.